# The cron job doesn't work when put in `/etc/cron.hourly/` but work when defined in `crontab -e`

Tags: cron

If I define my cron scheduler via `crontab -e`, the scheduler works correctly. However, putting the file in `/etc/cron.hourly/` doesn't work in my case.

Running `run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly` output the script. Also, the script name is `my_sql_backup` and doesn't have a file extension.

The script is `root:root` with 777 permission.

The `cron.hourly` scheduler seems to be working as this is the output of `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar  1 11:17:01 my-instance CRON[12919]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Also, if I manually ran the command, the scheduler ran just like it should:

```
sudo bash -c "cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly"
```

However, this seems to be not working actually. The script is back up MySQL database to Google Cloud Storage, but the storage isn't updated when I check it via Web Console.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Why does my scheduler script that was put in `/etc/cron.hourly/` not work?

---

#### UPDATE

Having added the `echo test > /tmp/foobar.tmp` line to my cron script, I found that the tmp file is there. In fact I found my own tmp file issued by the script.

The content of the script is the following. So maybe the problem occured in running `gsutil` command?

```
# define environment variables here
sudo sh -c "mysqldump -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DBNAME --single-transaction | gzip -9 > $MYSQL_TEMPPATH" >/dev/null 2>&1
gsutil cp $MYSQL_TEMPPATH gs://$GS_BUCKET_NAME/$MYSQL_S3_DESTPATH >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Again, the script worked fine if I manually ran it, so the environment variables are set to correct values...

---

#### UPDATE 2

I finally found that after getting the log file issued by `gsutil` command, it has the following content:

> AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation.

I still have to investigate why the access is denied if run in `/etc/cron.hourly/`... But the problem was on `gcloud`, not cron... Thank you for the support at the comments.

Comment: Having a 777 script that automatically runs as root is a major security vulnerability. You should change that immediately.

Comment: @JosephSible But isn't it a problem if no one enters the VM instance via SSH, right? I have little or no knowledge about security, though.

Comment: Whats the script interpreter?

Comment: No, it's also a trivial privilege escalation if whatever it is that VM is doing gets compromised.

Comment: @heemayl The first line is `#! /bin/sh`

Comment: So to make sure, the script is executable too?

Comment: @heemayl Yes, that's why manually running it via `cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` worked I think...

Comment: @Blaszard Great. Whats the output of `grep 'cron\.hourly' /etc/crontab`?

Comment: @heemayl  `17 * * * * root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`.

Comment: So i think your script is executing all right. You might have some quirk that if executed by `root` it can behave differently. To make sure either capture standard streams or add a line `echo test >/tmp/foobar.tmp` after the shebang line inside the script, and then check the content of `/tmp/foobar.tmp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54678/discussion-between-blaszard-and-heemayl).

Comment: @heemayl I updated my post.

Comment: *"the script worked fine if I manually ran it, so the environment variables are set to correct values"* not necessarily - unless you're setting EVERY environment variable (including ones that may be inherited from the calling process). For example, is `gsutil` on cron's `$PATH`?

Comment: @steeldriver I waited for another cron job to be run but found that `$PATH` outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin` in cron, and `which gsutil` returned `/usr/bin/gsutil`. So it is within `$PATH`...

Comment: Why do you use `sudo `in the script if it runs as root anyway?

Comment: @heemayl I can't as it has not passed 48 hours yet since the question is posted. I would in 23 hours, though.

Comment: @Blaszard Ahhh, ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the log output, I finally found that the log file included the following content which is from the `gcloud` execution:

> AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation.

So the problem was on `gcloud`, not cron.

#### So how to avoid the access denied error on gcloud?

In order to grant VM access the Cloud Storage, take the following steps:

1. Stop your VM instance
2. Edit your VM to change the Cloud Storage from *Read* to *Read/Write*.
3. Restart your VM

And now I finally got it working as scheduled...

The source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41604071/2360798

Answer (score -1):

You have not provided enough information on the script to understand what it's supposed to do nor why it might fail in a cron job - there are a couple common reasons.

However, your question's title and first paragraph (about user and root crontabs) seems clear enough, so let's answer that:

User crontabs and root crontabs have *slightly different formats*, and are not interchangeable.

Example:

```
1 1 * * * root /bin/foo   // root crontab in /etc/cron*
1 1 * * * /bin/foo        // user crontab in /var/spool (see it using the 'crontab' command
```

See the difference?  A root crontab has an extra field to specify the user. The user need not be root....though in practice it usually is root.

Let's say you want to run a database backup job. Add a root crontab to /etc/cron.d/ that triggers your backup script. Just trigger. One common mistake is to make the crontab more complex than it needs to be. All the logic and error-checking and permissions and logging should be in the script, not the crontab.

Comment: OP has put the script in `/etc/cron.hourly/`, and it is being invoked from `/etc/crontab` using `run-parts`. What does this answer provide to the context?

Comment: @heemayl edited to explain the context better. Thanks for the feedback.