# How to set up an hourly Cron job to run `grive` from `/etc/cron.hourly`?

Tags: cron, grive

I added the file `grive.sh` to `/etc/cron.daily` but the command doesn't seem to be running. I also copied it to `/etc/cron.hourly` but there has been no change to my Google Drive directory only. The file has only three lines:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /media/james/Seagate Expansion Drive/GD
grive
```

The permissions are read-only so I'll update those.

I used `/etc/cron.hourly# chmod u+rwx grive.sh`, but then when I check the permissions for the file in Nautilus, they are unchanged—I don't know why.

I can run `grive` manually from the terminal, and the files sync locally and online.

```
root@james-Streacom:/etc/cron.hourly# grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Feb  1 09:17:02 james-Streacom CRON[8696]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 10:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[10958]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 11:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[12897]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 12:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[15307]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 13:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[17043]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 14:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[17354]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  1 15:17:01 james-Streacom CRON[17705]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
root@james-Streacom:/etc/cron.hourly# cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
root@james-Streacom:/# bash -c "cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly"
root@james-Streacom:/#
```

Note that this may be a duplicate of [The cron job doesn't work when put in `/etc/cron.hourly/` but work when defined in `crontab -e`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888679/the-cron-job-doesnt-work-when-put-in-etc-cron-hourly-but-work-when-defined), I'm just going through those steps.

I added `echo test >/tmp/foobar.tmp` to the last line of the script.

```
root@james-Streacom:/etc/cron.hourly# grep 'cron\.hourly' /etc/crontab
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

`/temp/foobar.tmp` doesn't exist.

I tried to actually run `# cd /media/james/Seagate Expansion Drive/GD`, and got the error `-su: cd: too many arguments`. I then changed the cd line in the script to `cd /media/james/"Seagate Expansion Drive"/GD`.

`$ echo test >/tmp/foobar.tmp` does create the file with test in it.
`# echo test2 >/tmp/foobar.tmp` overwrites test with test2.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the unquoted whitespace in your original script (which you seem to have corrected) the issue is likely with the naming of your script.

According to the `DEBIAN SPECIFIC` section of `man cron`:

> ```
>    As  described  above, the files under these directories have to be pass
>    some sanity checks including the following: be executable, be owned  by
>    root,  not  be  writable  by  group or other and, if symlinks, point to
>    files owned by root. Additionally, the file names must conform  to  the
>    filename  requirements  of  run-parts: they must be entirely made up of
>    letters, digits and can only  contain  the  special  signs  underscores
>    ('_')  and  hyphens  ('-').  Any  file  that  does not conform to these
>    requirements will not be executed by run-parts.  For example, any  file
>    containing  dots  will  be  ignored.  This is done to prevent cron from
>    running any of the files that are left by the Debian package management
>    system when handling files in /etc/cron.d/ as configuration files (i.e.
>    files ending in .dpkg-dist, .dpkg-orig, and .dpkg-new).
> ```

Since `grive.sh` has a dot in its name, `run-parts` will ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, I renamed the file to `grive`, and will wait an hour and see whether it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question, although in my experience some commands doesn't work as expected when you add them into a script and put in a cronjob.

I'd start by adding it to new file in `/etc/cron.d/test` as following (I'll configure it every 5 minutes just to get some logs for testing purposes):

```
# m h  dom mon dow user command
*/5 * * * * root [DIR_TO_SCRIPT]/grive.sh >> /var/log/grivesh.log 2>&1
```

Please see stdout in `/var/log/grivesh.log`, once you have it analized you can have cronjob configured once every hour like this (e.g. at minute 5 every hour):

```
# m h  dom mon dow user command
5 * * * * root [DIR_TO_SCRIPT]/grive.sh >> /var/log/grivesh.log 2>&1
```

It is necesary to have it in `/etc/cron.hourly/`? Don't you preefer to have it in `/etc/cron.d/` or in a crontab for your user?

Regards,