# Run local user cronjob as root

Tags: cron

I'm attempting to run a cron job as root user, but it will not execute. Here's what I've tried...

1. Adding the job to my user crontab (crontab -e) and setting the user as root...

   ```
   17 10 * * * root /etc/cron.daily/cammedia.sh
   ```
2. Adding the job to the root user crontab (sudo crontab -e) and also adding the a few PATH's...

   ```
   PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/etc
   PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/scott
   PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/etc
   #
   0 4 * * * /etc/cron.daily/cammedia.sh
   ```

Here's the result of running crontab -l (local user account) after a test run:

```
May 26 10:17:01 WEBCAM CRON[89901]: (scott) CMD (root /etc/cron.daily/cammedia.sh)
May 26 10:17:01 WEBCAM CRON[89902]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 26 10:17:01 WEBCAM CRON[89900]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: User crontabs (i.e. those invoked using `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e` in the case of `root`) do not support an additional field to specify the user - that's only valid in the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab`. See `man 5 crontab` for discussion of the differences.

Comment: Please tell us _when_ (at what time, at what interval) you want your `cammedia.sh` to be executed.

Comment: Related: [How to set up an hourly Cron job to run `grive` from `/etc/cron.hourly`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001933/how-to-set-up-an-hourly-cron-job-to-run-grive-from-etc-cron-hourly)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. How then, do I get my user script to run as root, assuming it needs to be run as root? Also, I didn't gain anything from the link you presented, sorry.

Comment: @PerlDuck, I want to run this everyday, though the specific time is not really important; for example-sake, let's say run it @ 10:17 every AM.

Comment: @Scott Ok, then `/etc/cron.daily` is the right place. It is then executed by `anacron` (so grep for `anacron` instead). As Sebastian said in his answer you need to remove any extension (`.sh`) from the file.

Comment: @Scott IMHO it's more trouble than it's worth - you'd need to use `sudo`, and since cron runs non-interactively you'd need to configure your `sudoers` to allow it to authenticate without a password - once you've done all that, it's FAR simpler to run it as root natively, either from `sudo crontab -e`, from the system's `/etc/crontab`, or from `/etc/cron.daily`

Comment: @PerlDuck, in running the anacron syslog, it appears execution of scripts in cron,daily were attempted, however, received the following... `May 27 07:35:17 WEBCAM anacron[24963]: Job 'cron.daily' terminated (exit status: 1)` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the line completely. Simply placing a script in `/etc/cron.daily` will already make it run once a day. You will have to rename it to not contain the `.sh` suffix to be suitable for the cron.daily directory.

If you do not want to run it at the default time for cron.daily you should store the script elsewhere, e. g. `/usr/local/bin/cammedia.sh`.

If you plan to do this you should be aware that only root can run cron jobs as another user, for normal users it is not valid.

Do not forget to make the script executable by running `chmod +x cammedia.sh` in any case.

The output of the script will be e-mailed to you. If that is not possible (and according to the logs in your question it is not), the output will be discarded. There are other ways to get the output. E. g. you could add the following statement to the cammedia script:

```
logger "cammedia script run"
```

and you should see something in syslog.

A good read on the subject is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto, it will help you get your problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian, though I cannot get it to run simply by having it placed in the cron.daily folder. I removed the .sh extension, and I set & verifed 777 permissions on the file. The script functions perfectly if run independently. When I run 'grep CRON /var/log/syslog`, my script is not shown to have executed.